# Can $L|K$ be a Galois extension if $\text {Fix}_{G}\ (L) = K$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, proof-writing, field-theory, galois-theory

Let $L|K$ be a finite field extension. Let $G=\text{Gal}\ (L|K).$ Let us consider the set $$\text{Fix}_{G}\ (L):= \left \{x \in L\ |\ \sigma(x)=x,\ \text {for all}\ \sigma \in G \right \}.$$ Then $\text{Fix}_{G}\ (L)$ is a subfield of $L$ containing $K.$ If $\text{Fix}_{G}\ (L) = K$ can we say that $L|K$ is a Galois extension?

I have shown the converse of this result which states that "If $L|K$ be a finite Galois extension then $\text{Fix}_{G}\ (L) = K.$"

What I know about finite Galois extension are as follows $:$

$(1)$ **Theorem of primitive element for finite Galois extension** which states that "Every finite Galois extension $L|K$ is simple i.e. $\exists$ $x \in L$ such that $x$ is a primitive element of $L$ over $K$ or in other words $L=K[x]=K(x).$"

$(2)$ **Galois correspondence theorem** "if $L|K$ be a finite Galois extension then $L$ is finite Galois extension of any intermediary fields between $K$ and $L.$ Moreover there are inclusions reversing maps between the set of all intermediary fields between $K$ and $L$ and the set of all subgroups of $G=\text{Gal}\ (L|K)$ which are inverses of each other i.e. there exists a one to one correspondence between these two sets."

Now ho do I deduce the required result (if it is at all true) with the help of above results or theorems? What I observed is that if we can prove that $\# \text{Gal}\ (L|K) = [L:K]$ then we are through. How do I prove that? Any help will be highly appreciated.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Yes, this is true. If you have Galois correspondence , you have proved somewhere Artin's lemma, which says that if $H$ is a subgroup of ring automorphisms of a field $L$, then $L/Fix_H(L)$ is Galois. Now apply it to $H=Gal(L/K)$ and use your assumption.

Comment: Yeah got it. Thanks @GreginGre for your help.